# Labelling Columns by Intervals in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

Hi I am a bit stuck here. I am trying to create 3 labels for a contract called "Green","Yellow", and "Red". The labels are identified by the formula contractdate-curdate().
- Green if it is more than 90 days away.
- Yellow - if the = end date is between 31 and 89 days
- Red if the end date is 30 days or less

I need a way to either create a column for Label and put each contract in their respective color, or create 3 columns for each color with an identifier?

These are a couple queries i've made but with no luck.

```
select 
    contractname, contractenddate
from
    contract
where
    contractenddate between CurDate() and Date_Add(CurDate(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
        and contractenddate between CurDate() and Date_Add(CurDate(), INTERVAL 60 DAY)
and contractenddate between CurDate() and Date_Add(CurDate(), INTERVAL 90 DAY)
```

and

```
select contractname, date_sub(contractenddate,interval 0-30 day)as Red,
date_sub(contractenddate,interval 31-89 day)as Yellow,
date_sub(contractenddate,interval 90 day)as Green
 from contract
```

I know these are incorrect but perhaps someone could help build on these? It would be GREATLY appreicated!!! One last note is I am unable to alter the database structure, I can only use select statements.

Thanks a TON in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this work?  Look into using `DATEDIFF` and `CASE`:

```
SELECT contractname, 
  contractenddate,
  CASE
      WHEN DATEDIFF(CurDate(),contractenddate) <= 30 THEN 'Red'
      WHEN DATEDIFF(CurDate(),contractenddate) < 90 THEN 'Yellow'
      ELSE 'Green'
  END Label
FROM Contract
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27509/5).

And if you want the number of days away, you could add the following to your SQL Statement:

```
DATEDIFF(CurDate(),contractenddate) DaysAway
```

Alternatively, if you need Red, Yellow and Green as Columns, something very similar would work:

```
SELECT contractname, 
  contractenddate,
  CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CurDate(),contractenddate) <= 30 THEN 'X' ELSE '' END 'Red',
  CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CurDate(),contractenddate) < 90 AND DATEDIFF(CurDate(),contractenddate) > 30 THEN 'X' ELSE '' END 'Yellow',
  CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CurDate(),contractenddate) >= 90 THEN 'X' ELSE '' END 'Green'
FROM Contract
```

I've put an 'X' to mark which have which.  Wasn't quite clear what you were looking for.

More [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27509/4).

Good luck.